# Wordpress taxonomy template - Print mixed posts and sub taxonomies with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have WordPress task and it seems there is nowhere an answer available on this.

**What do I have:**
I have a custom taxonomy called "product_taxonomies" and custom post type called "products". In the taxonomy file called "taxonomy-product_taxonomies.php" I fetch all products belonging to the current taxonomy and I print them with pagination as well. So when I click on the taxonomy called "Product Category 1" I get all its products with pagination.

**What I need:**
I need to modify my code that for the current taxonomy it prints both its products and sub-taxonomies all mixed together and with pagination as well. So when I click on the taxonomy called "Product Category 1" I should get all its products and subcategories "Product Sub-Category 1", "Product Sub-Category 2" etc. with pagination. Pagination should work as if products and sub-taxonomies are the same thing and they should also look like they are the same thing:

[Here is the image showing how I want it to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l7KM.jpg)

**What I managed to do:**
I used get_categories() so as to get all sub-taxonomies of the current taxonomy and print them. The problem is that all the sub-taxonomies are not mixed with products and the pagination takes into account only the products and not the sub-taxonomies.

**Here is my code:**

```
<ul>
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $args1 = array(
'type'         => 'post',
'child_of'     => $current_id,
'parent'       => '',
'orderby'      => 'id',
'order'        => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'   => 0,
'hierarchical' => 1,
'exclude'      => 0,
'include'      => '',
'number'       => '',
'taxonomy'     => 'product_taxonomies',
'paged' => $paged,
'pad_counts'   => false );

$sub_terms = get_categories($args1);
foreach($sub_terms as $sub_term){
    //var_dump($sub_term);
    $sub_term_link = get_term_link($sub_term->slug, 'product_taxonomies');
    $sub_term_image = get_field('category_image', 'product_taxonomies_' . $sub_term->term_id );
?>
    <li class="mix">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="product_bg"><img src="<?php echo $sub_term_image['sizes']['product_images']; ?>" /></div>
            <div class="product-caption"><?php echo $sub_term->name; ?></div>
            <div class="overlay-div">
                <div class="overlay-text">
                     <?php echo $sub_term->category_description; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php
}           
            wp_reset_query();

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'products',
                'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
                'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_taxonomies',
                                'field'    => 'id',
                                'terms'    => $current_id,
                            ),
                        ),
                'paged' => $paged
            );
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
         if ($query->have_posts()) {
             $i=1;
             while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();

                 $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_taxonomies');
                 $tags = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag');
                 $all_terms = "";
                 foreach($terms as $single_term){
                    $all_terms .=  $single_term->slug . " ";
                 }
                foreach($tags as $single_tag){
                    $all_terms .=  $single_tag->slug . " ";
                 } ?>
                <li class="mix <?php echo trim($all_terms); ?>">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="product_bg"><?php the_post_thumbnail('product_images'); ?></div>
                        <div class="product-caption"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        <div class="overlay-div">
                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                 <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                 <?php $i++; 
             }
             wp_reset_query(); 
         }else{
            _e('Sorry, no available products under this category.','site');
         } ?>
</ul>  
<div class="pagination_area">
    <?php
    //global $query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => __('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left">&nbsp;</i>'),
        'next_text' => __('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right">&nbsp;</i>'),
        'type' => 'list'
    ));
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>
```